# Auto code completion in Visual Studio Q# IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, q#

Title says it all... I can’t find an option to trigger code completion or show me the available methods for a program. Is there even one?

Answer (score 0):

*Update:*
Code completion was added to Q# extension for Visual Studio 2019 in release [0.9.1909.3002](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/relnotes/#version-0919093002); it supports VS version 16.3 or later.

*Original answer:* 
Q# extension for Visual Studio doesn't have support for autocomplete (as of the latest release 0.4). This is a very frequently requested feature, and we hope to implement it soon.